# MongoDb agregation $project exclude all fileds except for one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have the following aggregation, and i want $project to exclude all fields except for 2 fields first_name and last_name

```js
  const aggregate = await this.aggregate([
            { $match: { chatRoomId: ObjectId(chatRoomId) } },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'partners',
                    localField: 'postedByPartner',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'postedByPartner',
                },
            },
            { $unwind: '$postedByPartner' },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "postedByPartner.first_name": 1,
                    "postedByPartner.last_name": 1,
                }
            },
            .
            .
            .
```

The excpected result is:

```js
          {
                "_id": "62a20226b8883346ce02a58b",
                "chatRoomId": "62a1d0e41bf0e22747d07301",
                "postedByPartner": {
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                },
                "message": "Hello",
                "readByRecipients": [
                    {
                        "readByPartnerId": "5f60e6445026b40278c5879e",
                        "readAt": "2022-06-09T14:22:21.551Z"
                    }
                ],
                "createdAt": "2022-06-09T14:22:30.336Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-06-09T14:22:30.336Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
```

But what i got actually is this,

```js
            {
                "_id": "62a208bd619771525e369368",
                "postedByPartner": {
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": ""
                }
            },
```

I just want to exclude postedByPartner fields and keep first_name and last_name, without modifying the rest

Comment: try converting string _id to objectId, `{ $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(post._id) } }`

Comment: thanks @turivishal it work with  { $match: { chatRoomId: ObjectId(chatRoomId) } }, but actualy my problem is with select only 2 fields from postedByPartner first_name & last_name any idea ?

Comment: what result are you getting now?

Comment: i got this 
            {
                "_id": "",
                "postedByPartner": {
                    "first_name": " ",
                    "last_name": ""
                }
            },
bu what i need is this
          {
                "chatRoomId": "",
                "postedByPartner": {
                    "first_name": "",
                    "last_name": "",
                },
                "message": "Hello",
                "readByRecipients": [
                    {  "readByPartnerId": "",
                        "readAt": ""  } ],
            },

Comment: Your question is not clear, you said you need *select only 2 fields from postedByPartner first_name & last_name* and you got your expected result, please update your question with proper details.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, i updated the question

Comment: what mongodb server version you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245465/discussion-between-ramzi-gz-and-turivishal).

Comment: there are 2 options if your mongodb version below 5.0, 1) add all fields in project stage that you want in result, 2) just remove all fields except first_name and last_name from `postedByPartner` in project stage by `0`

Comment: Thanks, just for information what would be the solution if the version was 5.0 ?

Comment: you can use both localField and pipeline syntax of [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#correlated-subqueries-using-concise-syntax). you can also use let and pipeline above 3.2 version but you have to add one more stage to match `postedByPartner` but it will not use index, if you have created.